# /proc kcore file is huge

Tags: proc

After experiencing a DDOS attack, somehow `/proc/kcore` is very huge, I use a small php class to check the current disk space, and how many has been used.

It shows the following:

```
Total Disk Space: 39.2 GB
Used Disk Space: 98 GB
Free Disk Space: 811.6 MB
```

My question is, is it safe to delete the `/proc/kcore` file? Or is there a solution on getting it to an normal size.

The filesize of `/proc/kcore` is 140.737.486.266.368 bytes

I have hosted my server at DigitalOcean.

If any more information needed to know, please ask ;)

Many thanks!

Edit...

`df -h` returns:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda         40G   37G  755M  99% /
udev            993M   12K  993M   1% /dev
tmpfs           401M  224K  401M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           1002M     0 1002M   0% /run/shm
```

`du -shx` returns:

```
du -shx *
8.7M    bin
27M     boot
12K     dev
6.3M    etc
4.8M    home
0       initrd.img
229M    lib
4.0K    lib64
16K     lost+found
8.0K    media
4.0K    mnt
4.0K    opt
du: cannot access `proc/3765/task/3765/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/3765/task/3765/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/3765/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/3765/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       proc
40K     root
224K    run
8.0M    sbin
4.0K    selinux
4.0K    srv
0       sys
4.0K    tmp
608M    usr
506M    var
0       vmlinuz
```

Results of `lsof | grep deleted`:

```
mysqld     1356      mysql    4u      REG              253,0           0    1835011 /tmp/ib4jBFkc (deleted)
    mysqld     1356      mysql    5u      REG              253,0           0    1835012 /tmp/ibcE99rr (deleted)
    mysqld     1356      mysql    6u      REG              253,0           0    1835013 /tmp/ibrxYEzG (deleted)
    mysqld     1356      mysql    7u      REG              253,0           0    1835014 /tmp/ibK95UJV (deleted)
    mysqld     1356      mysql   11u      REG              253,0           0    1835015 /tmp/iboOi8Ua (deleted)
    nginx     30057       root    2w      REG              253,0           0     789548 /var/log/nginx/error.log (deleted)
    nginx     30057       root    5w      REG              253,0 37730323404     268273 /etc/nginx/off (deleted)
    nginx     30057       root    6w      REG              253,0           0     789548 /var/log/nginx/error.log (deleted)
    nginx     30058   www-data    2w      REG              253,0           0     789548 /var/log/nginx/error.log (deleted)
    nginx     30058   www-data    5w      REG              253,0 37730323404     268273 /etc/nginx/off (deleted)
    nginx     30058   www-data    6w      REG              253,0           0     789548 /var/log/nginx/error.log (deleted)
    nginx     30059   www-data    2w      REG              253,0           0     789548 /var/log/nginx/error.log (deleted)
    nginx     30059   www-data    5w      REG              253,0 37730323404     268273 /etc/nginx/off (deleted)
    nginx     30059   www-data    6w      REG              253,0           0     789548 /var/log/nginx/error.log (deleted)
```

Comment: `/proc` should be a virtual filesystem afaik? You shouldn't get any actual diskspace back if you delete something there... Run a `df -h` to see actual used diskspace.

Comment: @Wrikken I have updated the post, theres 755 mb left.

Comment: Yep, seems like a problem, but not fixed with deleting something in `proc` (see the output of `mount`, it's just `procfs`). It's also a lot smaller then the 127TB you claim to have in `kcore`. There is a bit of cleanup to be done it seems, but not in `/proc`. I usually drill down from the root with `du -shx *`, see what the large directories are, and step further into those with another `du -shx *`, etc, to find the _real_ source. BTW: after a DDOS, it may not be a bad idea to rotate your logs away which could be filled to the brim with nonsense by running `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf `

Comment: @Wrikken i've updated the post again with the du -shx results, all folders seem to have a normal size, it only gives an error on the proc folders. I have pasted logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf in SSH but still have the same amount of mb's available.

Comment: Hm, well, the error in there is not important (just a process that ended between being discovered & checking its size). But that seems quite normal indeed.. What happens if you run it with `du -shx --apparent-size`? It may be sparse files... On a side note: I just noticed the file size of `/proc/kcore` in my Ubuntu install is... 140737486262272.. So, nothing to worry about, at least not _that_ one (officially, the file should be total amount of physical RAM + 4KB, but it seems my `man proc` documentation is lagging somewhwat.

Comment: @Rikken: du -shx --apparent-size returns 1.3G    .

Comment: What is the type of the / filesystem?  Also, have you looked for . (hidden) files in the root directory?

Comment: OK, that would mean there are a lot of actually deleted files, which are still not purged from the filesystem becuase some process keeps them open (their inodes still exist / are not deallocated yet). Could you have a look at `lsof | grep deleted` ? It will tell you which deleted files still exist, and which process id still has references to it. Usually, stopping or restarting that process will clean up the inodes.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Kiick how do I check the / filesystem? I'm not really great with servers, mostly i check guides on google lol.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Kiick: the `du -shx` (so without the `*`) Codemunkie has run doesn't care about whether files are hidden or not, it will still count them.

Comment: @Wrikken I have updated the post with the results and restarted nginx and mysql, which seemed to do the job. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Assuming I sufficiently answered your question, any chance you could mark my answer as accepted?  TIA!

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but one solution to tackle huge `/proc/kcore` is to restart the machine, which immediately reduce the size of the "file" to a much smaller size.

Answer (score 94):

In answer to your original question:

> "Is it safe to delete the `/proc/kcore` file? Or is there a solution
> on getting it to an normal size."

No, it's not safe.  Well, I wouldn't like to bet what would happen if you deleted it anyway!

The `/proc` directory is the mount point for procfs (run `mount` and see the output like below: )

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
```

procfs is a bit of dark magic; no files in it are real.  It looks like a filesystem, acts like a filesystem, and is a filesystem.  But not one that is stored on disk (or elsewhere).

`/proc/kcore` specifically is a file which maps directly to every available byte in your virtual memory ... I'm not absolutely clear on the details; the 128TB comes from Linux allocating 47ish bits of the 64bits available for virtual memory.

(There's discussion on the 128TB limit here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116640/what-is-maximum-ram-supportable-by-linux )

Anyway, putting aside Linux's hard-coded virtual memory limits - what we come to understand in the context of your question is this:  `/proc/kcore` is a system file, provided by the virtual procfs filesystem, and is not a real file.

Don't delete it ;-)

---

**Update: 2016-06-03**

My answer here keeps periodically being up-voted - so I assume people are still looking for an explanation of what `/proc/kcore` is.

There's a helpful Wikipedia article titled [Everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) which gives a little background.  If you're really curious - take a look into the Plan9 OS.

Hopefully my original answer sufficiently explains `kcore` itself.  I'm speculating that people reading this answer may be curious about other files in `/proc` too - so here are some other "interesting" examples.

- `/proc/sys/*` is a mechanism for the user (you) to read/write details from the heart of Linux (the kernel and associated drivers etc).  A cute example of a r/w item is "[IP forwarding](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux)":

  *Read:* `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` (`0` is off, `1` is on)

  *Write:* `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

  As with `kcore`, this isn't a real file.  But it acts like one.  So when you write to it, you're actually changing software settings as opposed to bytes on a disk.
- `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/cpuinfo` are read-only.  You can `cat` or `less` them, or `fopen()` from your own application.  They show you details about your hardware (memory and CPU).
- `/proc/[0-9]+` are actually *process IDs* running on your machine!  These are (IMHO) by far the coolest feature of `/proc`.  Inside them you will find more fake files like `cmdline` which tell you what command was used to start the process.

Finally there's some other examples of "interesting filesystems", like `/proc`.  There are [purely in-memory](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/) and ["user-space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) to name just two.  Again these (generally speaking) do not consume any real disk space, although tools like `df` and `ls` may report real file sizes.

Comment: It's in fact not possible to delete /proc/kcore, if you try it gives "Operation not permitted"

Comment: @tbodt I’ve never dared try!  Thank-you for the additional info.

Comment: The same is true for everything else in /proc

Comment: Sophos free virus scanner is getting stuck on this file. Seems like it is really scanning 128 TB :) Workaround: add this to the end of your savscan command line: `-exclude /proc/kcore`

Answer (score 9):

It's completely safe to run the command `sudo rm /proc/kcore`. It will just say `rm: cannot remove '/proc/kcore': Operation not permitted`.

All the files in `/proc` do not actually exist on your hard drive, so they can't be removed. Those files represent information about the system. For example, when you do `ls /proc`, you're asking the kernel for a list of the processes on the system. If you run `ls -l /proc/22/exe`, you're asking the kernel for the file path of the executable of process number 22. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your log file's space. I removed all error log and access log files and my Website is running.

Use this command to check which folder is taking more space:

```
cd /
sudo du -sh * 2>/dev/null | sort -h
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to clean up the disk of files that are deleted but are reserved. You can use the 'tune2fs' command with something like:

```
tune2fs -m 1 /dev/<drive>
```

This should free up the reserved block space and give you access to the privileged processes reserved disk space. Note that 1 is the percentage that will be allocated to the privileged processes afterwards, do this only if you have enough disk space for critical processes such as syslog, or ssh.

NOTE: You will never gain disk space by removing files from '/proc'. That is a virtual filesystem that has nothing whatsoever to do with space on your HDD.

Comment: The explanation about /proc is correct. I am not familiar with tune2fs; can someone explain what it does (and what's wrong with this answer, if anything)?

Comment: I can tell you that the reason I posted this answer was because it solved the same problem for me as what I perceived you to have. Not sure why it was down voted but if it solved your issue then that is great... Since the down-vote didn't give a reason, perhaps you could reinforce the answer with an affirmation to whether this was an answer that was useful to you.

Comment: I'm not the OP, nor did I have the same issue, just got here by chance, so I cannot reinforce the answer - I can only say that it seems reasonable to me and that it would be nice if the downvoter had left a comment. Other than that I'm just curious as to what `tune2fs` does.